# Accidently dd a whole disk with Iso file. Can i recover it ?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, dd, partition-recovery, testdisk

Here is the story buddies :

I dd'ed the wrong disk because of fdisk.

By disconnecting an reconnecting Usb and External HDD fdisk did not refresh results. The consequence is as you can see :

```
fdisk -l

Disque /dev/sdb : 14,5 GiB, 15552479232 octets, 30375936 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00022e59

Périphérique Amorçage Start      Fin Secteurs  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1    *         2048 30375935 30373888 14,5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

At this moment the external HDD is plugged in. ( i did not checked this, i know it sucks)

So i dd'ed the disk

```
dd bs=4M if=/home/spino/Isos/archlinux-2017.01.01-dual.iso of=/dev/sdb && sync
216+1 enregistrements lus
216+1 enregistrements écrits
909115392 bytes (909 MB, 867 MiB) copied, 0,95101 s, 956 MB/s
```

My eyes got a shady contact with the USB realizing the mess !

```
fdisk -l
Disque /dev/sdb : 931,5 GiB, 1000204885504 octets, 1953525167 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2eec075d

Périphérique Amorçage Start     Fin Secteurs  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1    *            0 1775615  1775616  867M  0 Vide
/dev/sdb2               172  131243   131072   64M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary
```

So i did not touch anything and just look around to find a solution.
I also checked these threads :

[Same problem with dd](https://superuser.com/questions/1044576/accidentally-overwrote-wrong-disk-with-dd-how-to-recover?newreg=3e8823f16e694175999039f6b19d0511)

[Testdisk suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/661683/how-to-recover-data-from-my-disk-i-accidentally-copied-with-dd-an-iso-on-it)

Here are my /proc/partitions after the disaster.

```
   8       16  976762583 sdb
   8       17     887808 sdb1
   8       18      65536 sdb2
```

Do any of you gentlemen have any idea how i can recover the partition on sdb it was a single 900GB partition in NTFS.

I am currently scanning the disk with testdisk.

I can submit other details of course.

For those who are reading thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accidentally overwrote wrong disk with dd, how to recover?](http://superuser.com/questions/1044576/accidentally-overwrote-wrong-disk-with-dd-how-to-recover)

Comment: I think it is not exactly the same situation. My problem concern only One partition on a Drive shrinked by an Iso file and not another partition . The problem linked is not very clearly explained.

Comment: It's NTFS, so you have the exact same issue as seen here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283009/84179 :) Use my program (RecuperaBit) and you will get most of the stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover overwritten NTFS partition?](http://superuser.com/questions/1146603/how-to-recover-overwritten-ntfs-partition)